# How to add a shortcut to a custom script in pyproject.toml (using poetry)

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I recently switched to Poetry from Pipenv. I'm used to having this section in my Pipfile:

```
[scripts]
test="pytest -s"
test:watch="ptw --runner 'pytest -s'"
```

so I can easily run my tests without typing out the full command or entering the shell, e.g.:

```bash
pipenv run test:watch
```

When I try something similar in pyproject.toml:

```ini
[tool.poetry.scripts]
watch = "ptw --runner 'pytest -s'"
```

I get an error:

```bash
$ poetry run watch

not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Is there a different section in the pyproject.toml that I should be using for this?

Comment: This is not what Poetry's `scripts` config table is for, it is meant for Python entry points. Check the [doc for `scripts`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts). -- What you want is something like [*poethepoet*](https://pypi.org/project/poethepoet/) and there are many other such solutions: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/task_runners.html

Comment: Anything else you need clarification? Anything I should add to my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[tool.poetry.scripts]` entries in a *Poetry* `pyproject.toml` file do not serve the same purpose as `[scripts]` entries in *Pipenv*'s `Pipfile`. Here is the [documentation for *Poetry*'s `scripts`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts). It is meant for [`console_scripts` *entry points*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/), and the values should be of the form: `importable.module:object.attr`.

What you might want to use to achieve your goal is something like [*poethepoet*](https://pypi.org/project/poethepoet/) or any other similar "*task runner*" tool, for example:

- [*chuy*](https://pypi.org/project/chuy/) (see also: [*poetry-chuy-plugin*](https://pypi.org/project/poetry-chuy-plugin/))
- [*doit*](https://pypi.org/project/doit/)
- [*invoke*](https://pypi.org/project/invoke/) (see also [*poetry-pyinvoke-plugin*](https://pypi.org/project/poetry-pyinvoke-plugin/))
- [*poethepoet*](https://pypi.org/project/poethepoet/)
- [*poetry-exec-plugin*](https://pypi.org/project/poetry-exec-plugin/)
- [*taskipy*](https://pypi.org/project/taskipy/)
- [*thx*](https://pypi.org/project/thx/)

Answer (score -4):

The error you're seeing suggests that there may be an issue with the command itself. One thing to check is if the command is correctly quoted, since `ptw` and `pytest -s` should be treated as separate arguments. Try changing your script definition to:

(c#)

```
[tool.poetry.scripts] watch = "ptw --runner 'pytest -s'"
```

To

(Swift)

```
[tool.poetry.scripts] watch = "ptw --runner \"pytest -s\""
```

and see if that resolves the error.

Comment: Where did you get this information from? Did you copy it from some other external resource? If yes, it would be helpful to provide a link to that resource.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is not correct at all. The issue is not with quotes, but that `[tool.poetry.scripts]` is not meant for something like this, it is a completely different feature (entry points).

Comment: Here is the documentation for `scripts`: https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts -- It is meant for `console_scripts` *entry points*, and the values should be of the form: `importable.module:object.attr`: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/

Comment: c#? swift? this is a python framework. also, if there was something wrong with the command then it wouldn't work on its own or in pipenv